# Term for 'Short frame of time'

Tags: phrases

I have sent a document for review by a peer, and I know he has a very short time in which to complete the review.

What is the formal way of telling him that I am sending the document at the last minute?

Comment: Please capitalize the first person pronoun. No need for capital 'W' in *What is the ...*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

> Sorry to leave you such a short **window** to respond

*[Window](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/window)* can mean

> an interval of time during which certain conditions or an opportunity exists

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about formal, but here are some idiomatic suggestions.

I apologise for sending this to you ...

...at the eleventh hour.
...so late.
...at the last minute.
...at the last moment.
...so late in the day.
...late, creating a bottleneck in the review process.